# hibernate show_sql value

Tags: java, hibernate

this is example of how sql is showed when using show_sql=true

```
Hibernate:
    select
        propertyse0_.entity_name as entity1_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.entity_id as entity2_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.entity_key as entity3_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.key_type as key4_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.boolean_val as boolean5_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.double_val as double6_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.string_val as string7_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.long_val as long8_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.int_val as int9_3_0_,
        propertyse0_.date_val as date10_3_0_
    from
        OS_PROPERTYENTRY propertyse0_
    where
        propertyse0_.entity_name=?
        and propertyse0_.entity_id=?
        and propertyse0_.entity_key=?
```

possible to show value to gather with the sql rather than '?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your logging leven to "TRACE".
In your log4j.properties (assuming your using Log4J):

> log4j.logger.org.hibernate=TRACE

Will result in lots of logging tough...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your logging framework to log this level of details. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) for the various loggers that Hibernate uses, and how to use them.

The particular one that you want is:

- `org.hibernate.type` - Log all JDBC parameters

Answer (score 0):

not directly. you can use [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) to log all the data that is sent over jdbc. It has a logger that inlines the prepared statement values.

Comment: can elaborate more how to integrate with spring+hibernate existing app

Comment: I created a proxy for my datasource in spring that added the logger spy of log4jdbc. And I have to admit that this is not done in 10 minutes. However, for my purpose it was worth the effort. But I just included it for my tests and not in the app server.